# how to print ajax response using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have to make ajax calls in for loop. ajax gives me a text/html response. Now I have to print that each response. I am doing the below code:

```
function printBill(printBills, lastBillNo, type,taxType,outletId,date){

var printableObjects=[];
printBills.forEach(function(data){
    lastBillNo++;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    $.ajax({
        url: contextPath+"/print/"+lastBillNo+"/"+type+"/"+taxType+"/"+outletId+"/"+date,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        async:false,
        success:function(response){

            printableObjects.push(response);  // pushing response to array.

        }
    });
});
 return printableObjects;
}
```

This function gives me the printableObjects as array.. now I want to print the objects inside of this object array.
To print this object I am using the below code:

```
function printIt(printableObj){
var counter = 0;
 var timer = setInterval(function(){
     printContent(printableObj[counter]);
    counter++;
    if (counter === printableObj.length) {
        console.log("clearing timer :"+counter+" length of the obj          :"+printableObj.length);
          clearInterval(timer);
         alert("Printing done ..");
          window.location.href="takeAway";

    }
},500);
console.log("============");
 return true;
}

function printContent(printDoc){
//console.log("Printing object is :"+el);
  var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
  var printcontent = printDoc;
  document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
  window.print();
  document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;
}
```

I am sending this print to sendToOne note. Whenever printing is happening that time my browser got struck. Please let me know any solution. No luck with me.

Comment: What is it that is not working? is `printContent` not printing anything? Have you waited for the ajax completion _before_ trying to print?

Comment: Move the ForEach loop on printableObjects inside the success. And no need to return printableObjects from printBill function.

Comment: the problem is browser is not responding after printing completed...

Comment: @TIMINeutron printContent is printing. but in forloop i am print the printableObjects giving me the problem. i am waiting for the ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move foreach loop after call is succedeed.

```
function printBill(printBills, lastBillNo, type,taxType,outletId,date){

 var printableObjects=[];
 printBills.forEach(function(data){
   lastBillNo++;
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
 $.ajax({
    url: contextPath+"/print/"+lastBillNo+"/"+type+"/"+taxType+"/"+outletId+"/"+date,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    async:false,
    success:function(response){

        printableObjects.push(response);  // pushing response to array.
        printableObj.forEach(function(d){
       // setTimeout(printContent(d),1000);
       printContent(d);
});


    }
});
 });
   return printableObjects;
}

function printContent(printDoc){
//console.log("Printing object is :"+el);
 var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
 var printcontent = printDoc;
 document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
 window.print();
 document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is all your code, you're *clearly* not waiting for all the ajax's returns.

Try this sample (can't test right now, sorry)

```
function printBill(printBills, lastBillNo, type, taxType, outletId, date, callback){
    //We create a new array, which essentially stores all the calls to ajax
    //so we can listen to all their completions.
    var requests=[],
        printableObjects = [];
    printBills.forEach(function(data){
       lastBillNo++;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        requests.push($.ajax({
            url: contextPath+"/print/"+lastBillNo+"/"+type+"/"+taxType+"/"+outletId+"/"+date,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            async:false,
            success:function(response){

                printableObjects.push(response);  // pushing response to array.
            }
        }));
        //We use $.when() to check for all the ajax call's completions and
        //execute a function when they're all done. the fn.apply() is being
        //used to pass each item as an individual parameter. 
        $.when.apply($, requests).then(
            callback(printableObjects);
        );
   });
   return printableObjects;
}
```

And you use it like so:

```
printBill(printBills, lastBillNo, type, taxType, outletId, date, function (printableObjects) {
    //Do something with that array - printableObjects
}
```

More info on [$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)
More info on [apply()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)